# Adding co-dependent checkout fields

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add two fields to my checkout form.  I run a website that sells offroad parts.  I would like to have a text box which the customer can enter their vehicle year/make/model.  If they do not want us to verify that the part is compatible with their vehicle I would like them to have to check a box saying as much.

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/ - Lesson 3 is perfect for adding the fields....but I don't know how to make the checkbox be required ONLY if the text box is empty.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was late last night I guess.  The answer is simple.  The following is from the link I posted in my original question.

```
/**
 * Process the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if (!$_POST['my_field_name'])
        $woocommerce->add_error( __('Please enter something into this new shiny field.') );
}
```

All that has to be done is the:

```
if (!$_POST['my_field_name'])
        $woocommerce->add_error( __('Please enter something into this new shiny field.') );
```

modified like:

```
if (!($_POST['my_field_name'] || $_POST['my_checkbox']))
        $woocommerce->add_error( __('Please enter something into this new shiny field or check the box.') );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about woothemes but here's a basic "checkbox is disabled if form is filled in" piece of code. You didn't tag your query with PHP so this is all basic javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>test</title>

<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox"></input>
<input type="text" name="myTextBox" id="checking" onblur="myTextBox(this);" onmousedown="myTextBoxActive(this);" />

<script>  


function myTextBox(field) {
    if (field.value == '') {
        document.getElementById('myCheckBox').disabled=false;
    }
}


function myTextBoxActive(field) {
    if (field.value == '') {
        document.getElementById('myCheckBox').disabled=true;
    }
}




</script>
```

Comment: This could work but I am looking for more of a server-side answer (although validation is generally done client-side via javascript, I know).  It may not be possible via php, but I added the php tag to my query just in case :-)  Thanks!